# twiiter app concepts

Tags: android, twitter

Can anybody explain me the concept of callback url.

1. How to set it while registering our app on twitter.
2. how to use it in the code and manifest file of application

Comment: Are you clear with Call back URL in Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest you this Java library [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)
I used it for a test project and it was working fine :)

Comment: can you please explain me the call back url concept

Answer (score 0):

About callback, in android manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="protocol" android:host="callback"/>
</intent-filter>
```

so callback will be: "protocol://callback"
I think it should work, cannot test it now.

Ohh, and open authorization page by this method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://......"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: ya but how to set it while registering  app on twitter

Comment: sorry, not sure I understand what you mean. You register twitter app once on the web, and get consumer key & secret. Also you'r able to set up additional options to describe your app, and callback as well. Then use that callback inside your android app. That's it. https://dev.twitter.com/apps/****/settings ?